# Rails ActiveRecord - fastest way of getting all invalid records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I recently updated some validations for my `User` table/model, and it has invalidated some previous rows/records. It's not a huge deal, but I would like to keep all records valid. What's the fastest way to do that for any table/model? Ideally this would be performant for a table with 100k records.

So far, I have something like:

```
invalid_users = []
User.find_each do |user|
  invalid_users << user if !user.valid?
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

This is pretty slow though, and with 100k records it would take a long time.

Comment: It is depend on your validations. Show user model.

Comment: I added an example model. Why would it depend on my validations? I'm looking for a general answer that would work for any given table that has validations.

Comment: Because the fastest way is to convert your validation to an SQL query and run that against the table.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM users WHERE username IS NULL OR name IS NULL UNION SELECT CONCAT(id) FROM users GROUP BY username WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND count(id) > 1`?

Comment: Ah makes sense. Thanks! Feel free to post the SQL query as an answer.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin `HAVING count(id) > 1` Where does not like aggregate functions

Comment: Also you could just validate (`user.valid?`) when the user logs in and if they have become invalid force them to update their record